# Find contiguous integers with a given sum

Tags: python, algorithm, interview-questions

## Introduction

This question was asked in a technical interview, I am looking for some feedback on my solution.

Given a list of integers and a number K, return which contiguous
elements of the list sum to K.  For example, if the list is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and K is 9, then it
should return [2, 3, 4].

## The Ask

My solution works with my test cases, but I would like feedback on *how others would approach the problem* and where my code could be altered to improve efficiency and runtime.  Currently, I have a nested for loop and I believe my solution is **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

## Solution

```
def contigSum(nums, k):

    for i, num in enumerate(nums): 
        accum = 0
        result = [] 
        # print(f'Current index = {i}')
        # print(f'Starting value = {num}')

        for val in nums[i:len(nums)]:
            # print(f'accum = {accum}')
            result.append(val)
            # print(f'accum = {accum} + {val}')
            accum += val 

            if accum == k: 
                print(f'{result} = {k}')
                return 0
            # else:
                # print(f'accum = {accum}')

    print('No match found')
    return 1
```

## Test Cases

```
nums0 = []
k0 = None 
contigSum(nums0, k0)

nums6 = [1, 2, 3]
k6 = 99
contigSum(nums6, k6)

nums1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
k1 = 9
contigSum(nums1, k1)

nums2 = [-1, -2, -3]
k2 = -6
contigSum(nums2, k2)

nums4 = [5, 2, 6, 11, 284, -25, -2, 11]
k4 = 9 
contigSum(nums4, k4)

nums5 = [10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 ,1]
k5 = 20 
contigSum(nums5, k5)
```

Comment: Why is *Lyft* part of your title as it's mentioned nowhere in the question? Also, why isn't [4,5] a valid answer if K is 9?

Comment: The question was asked by Lyft in a technical interview - I agree, it is not relevant to the question.  I'll remove it. [4, 5] is a valid solution, but I wrote my solution to stop at the first successful match.

Comment: I believe that specifying it is a technical interview might be useful to the question though (In my opinion) as it may orient the review in another way :)

Comment: Good point, thanks for your feedback @IEatBagels

Comment: The inclusion of negative integers makes it impossible, I think, to get a linear solution, unfortunately...

Comment: Also, if you include test cases, you should include the expected outcome as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Unused code

`for i, num in enumerate(nums):`, the `i` variable is used in your commented code, but commented code shouldn't exist, so `i` shouldn't exist either.

To come back on the commented code, I hope you didn't submit your solution with these comments as this is a (in my opinion) very bad practice. What does commented code mean after all? These comments could all be replaced by any debugging tool.

### Running time

<strike>I believe your solution is actually running on \$O(n*\log(n))\$  time as the nested loop doesn't restart at index 1 every time it runs (which is a good thing).</strike> Seems like this is wrong.

### Code structure

Usually, in an interview question code structure is pretty important. Right now you have one method that does everything. You should *at least* have a method that returns your result and one that prints it. Something like :

```
def main():
    nums = ...
    k = ...
    print(contigSum(nums, k))

def contigSum(nums, k):
    ...
```

and `contigSum` should **return** the result, not print it.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for pointing these out - much appreciated.

Comment: Even though _the nested loop doesn't restart at index 1 every time_ this one is still \$O(n^2)\$. Please double-check your reasoning.

Comment: @vnp You're right, I'm still struggling a little bit with the Big O notation.